# Always having the year display at my origin of a graph in AMCharts

Tags: amcharts

Good day all
I am having a bit of trouble. I have a graph that ranges from 2012 to 2015. I need my year to display at my origin once I zoom in. At this stage my the year only displays at the beginning of every year. It takes the place of January. Is it possible to do this?

```
chart3.addListener("zoomed", function(e) {
    var date = $( ".chartdiv3 .amChartsPeriodSelector .amChartsInputField" )
        .map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();
    $(this).html(date.join(' <i style="color: #F47C00;">to</i> '));
    chart3.panels[0].titles[1].text = "period - " + date[0] + " to " +     date[1];
    chart3.panels[0].validateData();
});
chart3.write('chartdiv3');
```

Comment: Code or fiddle? And please explain a bit more.

Comment: Hi again Gerric. I can't send you code, my data is in php, but if you open a simple amcharts live monthly line chart you will see that you get a year ; m ;m m; m; m; m; m; m; m; m; m; year display on your category axis, what I need is that when you zoom say between March and August for example, you can display the year you are in in some way. The boss believes that it is difficult to know what year you are in once you zoom because we have 3 years data. I hope that I made it more clear.

Comment: Thought about using the categoryBalloon for this? Or does it have to be shown as label? Or maybe in an external div?

Comment: Well it needs to change. if you zoom between 2014 and 2015 you need to see at the beginning of the category axis that you are in 2014. and so on with all the years. I don't know if I'm explaining correctly.

Comment: Ok. I can imagine two solutions: Change labelFunction depending on zoom. This will affect every label, so every label has the year appended. Or change the first lable on zoom event.

Comment: sound perfect. But how would a dumb blond like me do that?

Comment: I added the code I used for the zoom

Comment: Sry i was a bit busy and haven't really read your code until now. Is this solving your problem already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So changing the `labelFunction` depending on zoom is pretty easy.
Just take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mk1h3pyz/5/). (I used [this](http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/pc8p3/embedded/result,js,html,css/) as template).
The other approach is not as easy as i thought. You can modify the labels when the zoomed event is fired, however i haven't found a way to get the year for the first label. (it's an amcharts object containing the svg but no date, just the plain text for the label)

Comment: No worries. I think I can work with this. Thank you so much. Again